# Compare two multimaps and replace/remove values

Tags: java, multimap

I have two multimaps with Ids and names, one is filled with information that i get from a remote service and the second has information that i have in my local database. I need to compare and synchronize them.

```
Multimap<Long, String> remote
Multimap<Long, String> localDB
```

We can assume that ids are always the same but names can vary, e.g:

```
remote = {1 = [Tom], 2 = [Bob , Ron], 3 = [Philip]}
local = {1 = [Tom], 2 = [Johan, Robert], 3 = [Susan]}
```

And what i expect to get is:

```
local = {1 = [Tom], 2 = [Bob , Ron], 3 = [Philip]}
```

how can i get it?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254598/how-can-i-compare-two-multimaps

Comment: I have checked that post and it does not refer to my problem

Comment: You mean you want to put data from remote into local map?

Comment: yes, but only for these that do not match in order to synchronize them

Comment: @Marret To put one map into another, you can call putAll method with another map as argument. If there will be values with the same keys, value of key will be override.

Comment: Looks like you not really want a sync in both directions but only from remote to local, correct?

Comment: Thank you guys i will try it out,  @mle yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Extending the options from the comments above and assuming you'll just sync remote to local you have at least three different options:

- set one list itself on another: `local = remote;`
- remove all values from local which are not in remote and then do `local.putAll(remote);`
- copy the contents from remote to local: `local = ImmutableListMultimap.copyOf(remote);`